# mongodump against access control

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I was trying mongodump to backup some dbs in mongodb and I have auth enabled in my mongodb.

I have one super user with role: "root" and db: "admin"
and one with dbOwner for a specific db abc.

I tried this following command

```
mongodump --username admin --password "xyz" --authenticationDatabase admin


error - Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file dump/abc: mkdir dump: permission denied
```

may be I need to use the credentials of the dbOwner but I thought being the super user one can do that.

Pls tell me how to use these two credentials in mongodump command.

Comment: The error comes from local filesystem, not from mongo. The user who runs `mongodump` command has no permission to create a directory `dump` in current directory.

Comment: correct... that was really silly.........thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found this [answer](https://github.com/jeffutter/dokku-mongodb-plugin/issues/77) posted by kallko on Gihtub which helps me.

So to resolve it, you need to add a `sudo` just before the command and that's it. It works for me.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You just follow:

Syntax:

```
mongodump -d <databasename> -o <target directory>
```

Example:

```
mongodump -d user -o ./desktop/foldername.
```

Where: the user is a collection name and -o is an output file and folder name is an where 
 to store in the file.